# Manipulating Linux /dev nodes' settings for convenient parsing?

Tags: linux, parsing, lua, modem, tty

Recently, I've been trying to use Lua to capture my USB 3G modem link quality and network type by using the provided `/dev/ttyUSB2` device node to send commands to the modem and
parse the output.

Unfortunately, at the time I wasn't aware that these device nodes could be tampered with the
`stty` command, which made it extremely difficult to capture output as it would sometimes include commands written to the interface, at some times it would show nothing, and at some times it would even send me false data (possibly a result of carriage return and newline issues).

I've managed to set things properly by issuing the following command:

```
 os.execute("stty -F ".. device ..
  " time 1 -hupcl ignpar -opost -onlcr -isig -icanon -echo brkint -icrnl")
```

Now, sending `AT+ZPAS?` and `AT+CSQ` seems to produce consistency, but I'm wondering if someone knew of more useful settings I could possibly set for the node.

One thing that comes to mind is the fact that Lua's `io.read()` hangs while waiting for `EOF`
from the device, essentially halting the code forever, but it would be quite neat if there was a command that could render the device node as "command-response" so that I could safely read the whole output of one specific command, without fears.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you looking for a way to execute a command, and then get the command's output?

Comment: @YuHao At this point, I'm looking for almost anything that doesn't include non-standard libraries, essentially yes. I've set up a loop that checks for `ERROR` and `OK` responses as a means to stop the execution hang, but it is not reliable (sometimes, `AT+CSQ` returns `NO CARRIER`).

Comment: Does `io.popen` fulfill your requirement? It's not standard but many implementations provide it.

Comment: @YuHao Indeed, the requirement is that of the library I'm writing the script for, which mustn't depend on external libraries for convenient installation and use. `io.popen()` is generally used here to parse program output where not possible to access data in `/proc` or `/sys`.
So yes, I can use it, if you know of a command that can safely communicate with the device, that would be even awesome-er :D